# creating multiple python class instance from json

Tags: python, json

I am writing some tests to evaluate a rest service
my response is

`[
  {
    "Title_Id": 1,
    "Title": "Mr",
    "TitleDescription": "Mr",
    "TitleGender": "Male",
    "Update_Date": "2012-07-21T18:43:04"
  },
  {
    "Title_Id": 2,
    "Title": "Mrs",
    "TitleDescription": "Mrs",
    "TitleGender": "Female",
    "Update_Date": "2012-07-21T18:42:59"
  },
  {
    "Title_Id": 3,
    "Title": "Sir",
    "TitleDescription": "Sir",
    "TitleGender": "Male",
    "Update_Date": null
  }
]`

and need to create multiple instance of the class

```
class TitleInfo:
  def __init__(self, Title_Id, Title, TitleDescription, TitleGender, Update_Date ):
    self.Title_Id = Title_Id
    self.Title = Title
    self.TitleDescription = TitleDescription
    self.TitleGender = TitleGender
    self.Update_Date = Update_Date
```

what I have done is

```
def GetTitle(self):
  try:
    response = *#......"The string shown above"*
    if  isinstance(response, str) :
      Records = json.loads(response)
      RecTitles = []
      for num in range(0, len(Records)):
        RecTitle =TitleInfo(Records[num]['Title_Id'],Records[num]['Title'],Records[num]['TitleDescription'],Records[num]['TitleGender'],Records[num]['Update_Date'])
        RecTitles.append(RecTitle)
```

This is working fine ....I need to know is there more short and sweet way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just unpack each `dict` and give that as an argument to `TitleInfo`:

```
RecTitles = [TitleInfo(**x) for x in json.loads(response)]
```

Here's the explanation from [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

> In the same fashion, dictionaries can deliver keyword arguments with the **-operator:

```
>>> def parrot(voltage, state='a stiff', action='voom'):
...     print("-- This parrot wouldn't", action, end=' ')
...     print("if you put", voltage, "volts through it.", end=' ')
...     print("E's", state, "!")
...
>>> d = {"voltage": "four million", "state": "bleedin' demised", "action": "VOOM"}
>>> parrot(**d)
-- This parrot wouldn't VOOM if you put four million volts through it. E's bleedin' demised !
```

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, you generally want to avoid hand-coding validation code. Checkout an API documentation framework: swagger, RAML, API Blueprint. All of them have tooling for request/response validation.

The next step would be to use a testing framework like [dredd](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd).