# Dynamically create classes- Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, namedtuple

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to create classes in a dynamic manner based on the contents of a JSON file. So for example, here's a snippet from the JSON file:

```
{
"stuff": [{
        "name": "burger",
        "aka": ["cheeseburger", "hamburger"]
    },
    {
        "name": "fries",
        "aka": ["french fries", "potatoes"]
    },
    {
        "name": "meal",
        "items": [{
                "name": "burger",
                "value": "<burger>"
            },
            {
                "name": "fries",
                "value": "<fries>"
            }
        ]
    }

  ]
}
```

And now based on this JSON, I want classes that represent these objects. So for example, something like:

```
class Burger:
   def __init__(self):
   self.name = "burger"
   self.aka = ["cheeseburger", "hamburger"]

class Meal:
   def __init__(self):
   self.name = "meal"
   self.burger = Burger()
   self.fries = Fries()
```

So basically, based on that JSON, I want to be able to create classes that represent the same attributes and relationships that we see in the JSON. Any ideas about the best way to approach this would be appreciated!

Comment: I've done something similar with mapping FileMaker schema to classes. I just used the attributes to write out a file and then load that file. I imagine you could do pretty much the same.

Comment: Why would you want to write code in JSON? Why not just write the classes ... you know like a `.py` file

Comment: I imagine the JSON file already exists.

Comment: @rdas I'm not writing the code in JSON, the JSON already exists and the idea is to be able to use that to create the class

Comment: this question was asked before and answered: for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336305/creating-multiple-python-class-instance-from-json

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison How would this work, if the schema isn't fixed and is dependent on what's in the JSON, so we have no idea about what may/may not be there in terms of the schema in advance. Could you also point me to an example that demonstrates what youre talking about? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need it to be a class? A python class is little more than a dictionary after all...

Comment: @RadosławCybulski My question isn't really the same. I want to know how to do this dynamically, there isn't a fixed schema, I can't use the fixed schema like in the question you've mentioned.

Comment: @ImperishableNight I don't need the full class implementation necessarily, but I need some way of being able to access those attributes by key without using a dict while also preserving relationships (like we see for example the meal consisting of the burger and fries)

Comment: Well, you are asking for something impossible, because when you use a python object, you *are* using a dict. It is the underlying representation of python objects.

Comment: Also, do you need a *class*, or just some individual duck objects? I feel like creating classes at runtime is unlikely to be useful...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194921/discussion-between-imperishable-night-and-david-west).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `json` variable contains your json data try this:

```
for d in json:
    name = d.pop('name')
    t = type(name, (object,), d)
```

What it does is to call `type`, which will create new type in python (exactly the same as if you did `class name`, which correct name set to content of `name` variable, with base class `object` and attributes in `d`. Variable `t` will contain class object you want.